# How to list all matches with multiple inputs in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have my data like the above image.

i want to achieve my output like the below image

[image]

I want to list all matching product codes for the given categories.

FILTER works for single input.

But i need a single formula which works for multiple inputs.

Test sheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YmilAMPVv5zgAGJpfX-f-FWTS2HtfdJGiAPBwbmLpE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use COUNTIF.

```
=FILTER(B:B,COUNTIF(E:E,A:A))
```

#### Update

```
=FILTER({B2:B,C2:C*VLOOKUP(A2:A,E2:F,2,0)},COUNTIF(E2:E,A2:A))
```

Comment: It works great. But i have a follow up question. i have added a qty column now. Also the input has one more column now.  I want the product of these two in the output. How can i achieve that? Can you please check Sheet 2?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach would help: FILTER column B according to the values in column A. With XMATCH you'll know if they're there, with ISNA you'll know if it throws an error (meaning it doesn't match), and if it's NOT an error then it will be listed:

```
=FILTER(B:B,NOT(ISNA(XMATCH(A:A,E:E))))
```

[image]